# Блок схема foreach

Tags: c#, блок-схема

Как изобразить на блок схему цикл foreach?

```
foreach (Order p in order)
{
    states[i] = new StateOrder(p.id, p.client, p.dateOrder,p.costOrder, p.haircut, p.admin);
}
```

Comment: Так же, как и для цикла FOR, Только вместо проверки счётчика "Равно ли конечному значению?" и действия "Прибавить один" используйте проверку "Есть ли ещё записи?" и действие "Взять следующую".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используется тот же самый элемент, что и для любого другого цикла.

Если речь идет о ГОСТовых блок-схемах, то используется два блока "3.2.2.6. Граница цикла".

Для UML Activity Diagram используйте составную Activity со стереотипом "Loop".

Если злой препод разрешает пользоваться только базовыми блоками - разворачиваете цикл в соответствии со спецификацией языка и рисуете блок-схему для него:

```
var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
try {
  while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    var current = enumerator.Current;

    // Тело цикла

  }
}
finally {
  if (enumerator is IDisposable)
    ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
}
```